# Do we need to understand Hashem better? Is this a commandment?

Tags: faith-bitachon-emunah, ikarim

Do we need to understand Hashem better? Is it a commandment?

There is Kabbalah, Torah, Talmud and so on. But is there a commandment that says we need to understand Hashem better? His plan for creation, angels, deep knowledge of the Torah.

Is it enough to be a good person and do teshuva and so on?

This question is for conservative and orthodox judaism, not reformed.

Answer (score 3):

here is a quote from the end of part 1 of chovos halevavos which I think answers your question. The next section called the shaar bechina (gate of examination) goes into this topic more.

> Therefore, you should exert your mind until you know the Creator
>   through the evidences of His works and not strive to know Him in His
>   glorious essence. For He is exceedingly close to you from the side of
>   His deeds but infinitely remote in any representation of His essence
>   or comparison with it. As already stated, we will never be able to
>   find Him in this way. When you arrive at the stage where you abandon
>   (trying to find Him) through your thoughts and senses because He
>   cannot be grasped in this way, and you instead find Him in the
>   evidence of His deeds, as though He were inseparable from you - this
>   is the pinnacle of knowledge of Him which the prophet exhorts us on in
>   saying "Know therefore this day, and consider it in your heart, that
>   the L-ord He is G-d in heaven above, and upon the earth beneath: there
>   is none else" (Deut. 4:39).

And a quote from the shaar bechina ch.2

> The examination of created things and deducing from them the wisdom of
>   the Creator is a duty which can be demonstrated from Reason,
>   Scripture, and Tradition (the oral torah)...

Likewise in Rambam's mishne Torah (yesodei torah ch.2)

> It is a mitzvah to love and fear this glorious and awesome God, as
>   written: "And you shall love God, your Lord" and, as [Deuteronomy
>   6:13] states: "Fear God, your Lord." (Deut. 6:5) What is the path [to
>   attain] love and fear of Him? When a person contemplates G-d's great
>   and wondrous deeds and creations, and he observes through them His
>   infinite wisdom which surpasses all comparison, he will immediately
>   love, praise, and glorify Him, yearn with tremendous desire to know
>   God's great name, as David stated: "My soul thirsts for the Lord, for
>   the living God" [Psalms 42:3].

Comment: Good answer,If I don`t get a better answer soon I will accept this one."Evidences of His works " I like that.Sound fair,I wish there was more on this "topic" and I guess there is...But the answer tells much about what we are looking for,but not if we "need to",saying "you should"Is not a commandment.

Comment: @Eagel there is lots more. infinitely more, especially in our times. have a look at this to see what i mean http://dafyomireview.com/446 regarding your 2nd point. i'll update the question

Comment: In your edit:You write "duty" from the oral Torah.But not a clear Torah commandment,I would say.Thanks for the edit

Comment: @Eagel duty means mitzva. I added the quote from the Rambam also which says the words u want

Comment: Ok,but would you say"another question" that to study Kabbalah is a mitzva?

Comment: @Eagel personally i think one of the main purposes of kabala is to bring one to a state of total awe of the wisdom and power of God (yiras haromemus) but today with the advances in science one can reach this quite easily just by studying nature. ex. the cell, fine tuning of the big bang/universe, various biological systems

Comment: Rav Noach Weinberg has a wonderful lecture series on this topic and many more fundamentals of what we can know about Him. You can listen to them freely here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c4vvft79gzn32lt/AABl72vhKPhV8B-Dxw2ahRCta?dl=0

Comment: @ray " just by studying nature"Thats all good,but I would say,then  what about angels and so on? Not easy to see angels by studying nature,and i would think Gods wisdom is even greater in the spiritual world.Thank you for you answer anyway

Comment: @Chaim Thank you,listening to it right now

Comment: Totally different conversation, but there are really two very different topics: there is definitely an obligation to know G-d as well as one is able. The question is whether there is an obligation to know **about** G-d. Totally different thing. To quote R/Dr Sholom Carmy:

The people who keep insisting that it's necessary to prove things about
G-d, including His existence, seem to take it for granted that devising
these proofs is identical with knowing G-d.

Now if I know a human being personally the last thing I'd do, except as a
purely intellectual exercise, is prove his or her existence.

Comment: @MichaBerger I agree,but: Hosea 4:6my people are destroyed from lack of knowledge. "Because you have rejected knowledge, I also reject you as my priests; because you have ignored the law of your God, I also will ignore your children.

Comment: @Eagel: The lack of knowledge is halakhah, not theology. The Rambam and other philosophical rishonim made a big deal about knowing theology. In fact, the closing thought of his Guide to the Perplexed is how such knowledge is the ultimate human perfection. (And along the way he associates it with prophecy and with receiving personalized Divine Providence.) The Rambam goes so far as to consider ethics a handmaiden, learning about G-d by emulating Him. However, that's not the only Jewish Philosophy out there. As I said in my prior comment, that is an open question.